# Is there a way to do a check for pinned messages, and only purge a certain members messages using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a purge command similar to Dyne's, where you can input a user, and it doesn't purge pinned, only the user's messages (if you input a user). I've tried making a seperate check function, but it doesn't purge anything. I get no error, it just won't purge.

```
@commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def purge(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None, num: int = 10000):
        if user:
            def check_func(user: discord.Member, message: discord.Message):
                return not msg.pinned
                return user.id
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=num, check=check_func)
            verycool = await ctx.send(f'{num} messages deleted.')
            await verycool.delete()

        else:
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=num, check=lambda msg: not msg.pinned)
            verycool = await ctx.send(f'{num} messages deleted.')
            await verycool.delete()
```

I have manage messages permissions on the server. Does anyone know how to make the check_func work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes I have made should solve your issue as well as deal with a few other issues.

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(self, ctx, num: int = None, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user:
        check_func = lambda msg: msg.author == user and not msg.pinned
    else:
        check_func = lambda msg: not msg.pinned

    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=num, check=check_func)
    await ctx.send(f'{num} messages deleted.', delete_after=5)
```

Just changing the function based on the arguments looks better and is more efficient as otherwise you have duplicated code. Furthermore, the message you send at the end was being deleted effectively immediately. `channel.send` has an argument `delete_after` which will automatically deletes a message after a given amount of seconds. There are a few other syntax issue I haven't mentioned such as the check function only taking one argument but you parsing two which I have also fixed. Technically PEP8 prohibits storing lambda's in variables but I think this could be excused.

**Edit**: you could do something like check if `num == "*"` and delete all messages if it does.