# discord.py - How to purge messages from a mentioned user?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62224912/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-check-for-pinned-messages-and-only-purge-a-certain-membe) but for some reason it doesn't when I mention a user. It doesn't show any errors on the terminal when I execute the command. The code looks like this from the question:

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(self, ctx, num: int, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user:
        check_func = lambda msg: msg.author == user and not msg.pinned
    else:
        check_func = lambda msg: not msg.pinned
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=num, check=check_func)
    await ctx.send(f'{num} messages deleted.', delete_after=5)
```

It works with only a number of messages like `q!purge 5` but not with `q!purge 5 @SomeUser#1234`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [`Channel.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.history)

```py
@bot.command()
async def purge(ctx, limit=50, member: discord.Member=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    msg = []
    try:
        limit = int(limit)
    except:
        return await ctx.send("Please pass in an integer as limit")
    if not member:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
        return await ctx.send(f"Purged {limit} messages", delete_after=3)
    async for m in ctx.channel.history():
        if len(msg) == limit:
            break
        if m.author == member:
            msg.append(m)
    await ctx.channel.delete_messages(msg)
    await ctx.send(f"Purged {limit} messages of {member.mention}", delete_after=3)
```