# How to clear if I have member.mention?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

````py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx,member : discord.Member,amount=200):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    if amount > 200:
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}merci de clear entre 0-200 message(s)")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"j'ai clear {amount} message(s)",delete_after=5)```
````

error:

```
File "C:\Users\dzzdz\PycharmProjects\pythonProject12\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 451, in _actual_conversion
    ret = await instance.convert(ctx, argument)   
File "C:\Users\dzdz\PycharmProjects\pythonProject12\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 195, in convert
    raise MemberNotFound(argument) discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound: Member "300" not found.
```

In this error, we can see that the command works only if I do !clear @ (amount).
If I remove the discord.member it's working. I can't remove the discord.member because one can't have an optional argument that comes before a default argument.
So what can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py - How to purge messages from a mentioned user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63334052/discord-py-how-to-purge-messages-from-a-mentioned-user)

Comment: Do you just want to mention a user that used the command?

Comment: none type dont have attribute mention,so no its might be doesnt work,and i want !clear (int) btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some errors that I noticed:

**First)** Since you are looking for the author of the message, `member` is not relevant here at all. We can simply use `ctx.author` for this and then display it as desired.

**Second)** You have a logic error in your code. Your `if amount >200` statement is not considered the way your code is and then more than 200 messages can be deleted without the error message showing up.

**One possible code would be:**

```py
@client.command() / @bot.command() / @commands.command() # Depends on what you use
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=200):
    if amount > 200:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} merci de clear entre 0-200 message(s)")
        return # Do not proceed
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"j'ai clear {amount} message(s)", delete_after=5)
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount) # Clear messages if lower than 200
```

Comment: i aldready tried ctx.author...and the problem with the amount i aldready know,thank you for the answer !

Comment: @Theoksksj So what is the actual problem then?

Comment: @Theoksksj I see you accepted an answer that is the same like mine. What was the reason for accepting the other one? Just so I know for the future. In my eyes it does not make any sense that you can mention someone else in a `command` you executed.

Comment: no haha i can’t accept 2,and yes your way might be work perfectly fine(2 answer are the same),i will accept yours if you want i just clicked randomly lol

Comment: @Theoksksj Feel free to accept the answer that helped you the most, I was just confused and asked for clarification. I don't want to persuade anyone here to see my answer as correct! :)

Comment: your answer was helped me the most ^^ haha you answered first

Comment: I'll take it that way, then. Happy coding and maybe we'll see you here again! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted your question as "I want to have a user, but if I don't mention the person I get an error. Help?" There are a few ways to do this of course, so I will show you two of them.

**Method 1**: Using `None`

If you do not want to use any extra imports, you can move your `member` to the front and make it `None`. For both the methods, you will need to use an if statement to change your `member` to the `ctx.author`.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx,amount=200,member : discord.Member=None): # moved the member to the right
    if member == None: # if no one is mentioned
        member = ctx.author # default to ctx.author
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    if amount > 200:
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}merci de clear entre 0-200 message(s)")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"j'ai clear {amount} message(s)",delete_after=5)
```

**Method 2**: Using [`typing.Optional`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#typing-optional).

This is often used as an optional argument. This allows for your `member` to be left in the middle.

```py
import typing

# ...
# other code

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, member: typing.Optional[discord.Member]=None, amount=200): # member is kept in the middle
    if member == None: # if no one is mentioned
        member = ctx.author # default to ctx.author
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    if amount > 200:
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}merci de clear entre 0-200 message(s)")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"j'ai clear {amount} message(s)",delete_after=5)
```